# What is the limit on malloc parameter of type size_t in C? Docs say it has an upper limit of UINT_MAX but I can't go beyond INT_MAX

Tags: c, malloc, limit, size-t

I want to allocate a 2.9GB char array with

```
  database = (char*) malloc((2900 * 1000000 * sizeof(char)));
```

This gives an integer overflow warning and the `malloc` returns `NULL`. The
`malloc` parameter is of type `size_t` which according to documentation is of type 
`unsigned int`.

So the max should be `UINT_MAX` which is at least 2.9GB. However, if
I try to allocate more than `MAX_INT` the `malloc` fails. Does this mean 
`size_t` on my system is of type int? How do I check this? I looked through

```
/usr/include/stdlib.h
```

and

```
./lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/include/stddef.h
```

but
can't find the definition of `size_t`. Thanks very much

Comment: It means you don't have enough RAM :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have 12GB RAM on the computer.

Comment: You also forgot to mention that your system is 32-bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, the overflow warning:  both `2900` and `1000000` are of type `int`, so the result of multiplying them is also of type `int`.  The result cannot be represented by a 32-bit signed integer, so it overflows.  You need to cast one (or both) arguments to `size_t` to use unsigned arithmetic.

(Or, you could move the `sizeof(char)` to be one of the first two terms, since its type is `size_t`, though you can also just remove the `sizeof(char)` since it is always `1`.)

Second, the maximum size that `malloc` can allocate depends both on the platform on which you are running and on the current state of the program.  If there is insufficient contiguous address space left to satisfy the request, obviously the `malloc` will fail.

Further, the platform on which you are running may have an upper limit on how large an object it can dynamically allocate.  You'll need to consult your platform's documentation to find out what that upper limit is.

`size_t` is certainly not `int`, because `int` is always signed and `size_t` is always unsigned.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still wondering where size_t is defined. Shouldn't it be in one of the two files I named in my post?

Comment: Yes, it should be defined in `<stddef.h>`, or some header included by `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: You'd be better off using `strtoul`, which returns an `unsigned long`, and actually allows for error checking.  An `atoi` failure is indistinguishable from a successful parse of the value zero.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the earlier comment because it didn't seem appropriate to post a question different from the thread's topic. In any case, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Or you could postfix your integers with "u"... See example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11310482/866618

Answer (score 10):

The parameter is of type `size_t` and `malloc` is required to accept any possible value of type `size_t`. Note that "accept" does not meant it is required to allocate that much; all it means is that `malloc` is not allowed to misinterpret a very large number you give it as a small/negative number due to overflow issues, thereby returning a buffer that's too small and creating a critical undetectable vulnerability your program cannot defend against. There are many possible reasons `malloc` could fail to allocate very large objects:

- that much memory is not available from the system
- due to fragmentation, no contiguous range of virtual addresses that large is available
- arbitrary limits

In this case I suspect you might be seeing the third, arbitrary limits, though I would not consider them so arbitrary. There's a very good reason to disallow allocations (and the existence of any objects) larger than `SIZE_MAX/2`: taking the difference between pointers within such large objects will result in (extremely dangerous) integer overflow and undefined behavior when the result does not fit in the (signed) type `ptrdiff_t`. Thus, on a robust 32-bit system, while the virtual address space size is 4GB, the maximum size of any single object will be 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size that malloc can allocate depends both on the platform on which you are running and on the current state of the program. If there is insufficient contiguous address space left to satisfy the request, the malloc will fail obviously.