# Is the integer constant's default type signed or unsigned?

Tags: c

Is the integer constant's default type signed or unsigned? such as 0x80000000, how can I to decide to use it as a signed integer constant or unsigned integer constant without any suffix?

If it is a signed integer constant, how to explain following case?

```
printf("0x80000000>>3 : %x\n", 0x80000000>>3);
```

output:

```
0x80000000>>3 : 10000000
```

The below case can indicate my platform uses arithmetic bitwise shift, not logic bitwise shift:

```
int n = 0x80000000;

printf("n>>3: %x\n", n>>3);
```

output:

```
n>>3: f0000000
```

Comment: Usually, `0x80000000` is `INT_MAX + 1`, so it's unsigned. Hence logical shift in the first example. But when you assign it to an `int`, you invoke undefined behaviour, and typically the result is `INT_MIN`. Left shifting negative integers is implementation-defined, often arithmetic shift is used. The difference is that in the latter, you force it to a signed type.

Comment: @DanielFischer  `INT_MAX + 1` is UB but `int n = 0x80000000;` is not UB but implementation-defined and the integer conversion in this case  is ruled by 6.3.1.3p3 (in C99)

Comment: @ouah The `INT_MAX + 1` was meant as a mathematical expression, not C. It's correct, however, that converting that to `int` isn't undefined behaviour, but implementation-defined. My bad.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

C has different rules for decimal, octal and hexadecimal constants.

For decimal, it is the first type the value can fit in: `int`, `long`, `long long`

For hexadecimal, it is the first type the value can fit in: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`

For example on a system with `32-bit` `int` and `unsigned int`: `0x80000000` is `unsigned int`.

Note that for decimal constants, C90 had different rules (but rules didn't change for hexadecimal constants).

Comment: The only correct answer so far. (Nits: you didn't specify the rules for octal [see hex], and from C90, hexadecimal literals changed by the addition of the `long long` types).

Comment: but then can't we expect a warning in `int n = 0x80000000;` Because it is assigning a uint32_t to a int32_t and somehow overflows ?

Comment: Does this mean the statement "An integer constant like 1234 is an int." in [K&R2] is wrong?

Comment: @VictorS: No, it's correct - 1234 is within the guaranteed minimum range of `int` so it will always have type `int`.

Comment: @mbonnin some compilers *can* display a warning but the standard does not require a warning. There are implicit conversions between any arithmetic types to any arithmetic types.

Comment: +1 for the only correct answer to a topic that's widely misunderstood.

Comment: If a compiler included a type whose length was intermediate between that of an `int` and a `long` [e.g. when compiling code for 8-bit microcontrollers a 24-bit type could be useful and I've seen at least one compiler support one as "short long"], could it legitimately participate in the hex constant evaluation?

Comment: @supercat The only provision in the C Standard for extended integer types in the integer constant typing is: *(c11, 6.4.4.1p6) If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list, it may have an extended integer type, if the extended integer type can represent its value [...]*. For other integer constants, a standard integer type (e.g, `int`, `long`) will be selected.

Comment: I wanted to check by myself and i confirm that `2147483648 << 1 >> 1` and `0x80000000 << 1 >> 1` look the same, but the latter resolves to 0 (on 32bit `int` machine).

Comment: Also, gcc will ultimately use `unsigned long long` for decimals with the warnings: `integer constant is so large that it is unsigned` and `this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90`

Comment: "For example on a system with 32-bit int and unsigned int: 0x80000000 is unsigned int" - 0x80000000 is perfectly capable of representing a 32-bit signed value which is -2147483648? Why is then "unsigned int" chosen?

Comment: Was the decimal constant rule changed in C95?  What were the rules for C90?  Do you know the exact section of the ANSI C spec this is documented?

Answer (score 9):

It is signed **if it fits in a signed integer**. To make it unsigned, append a `u` suffix, e.g. `1234u`.

You can *convert* a signed value to unsigned by assigning it to an unsigned variable.

```
unsigned int i = 1234u; // no conversion needed
unsigned int i = 1234;  // signed value 1234 now converted to unsigned
```

For `0x80000000`, it will be **unsigned** if ints are 32 bits on your platform, since it doesn't fit into a signed int.

---

Another thing to watch out for, though, is that the behaviour of right-shift is platform-dependent. On some platforms it's sign-preserving (arithmetic) and on some platforms it's a simple bitwise shift (logical).

Comment: Updated to answer your additional query.

Comment: `0x80000000` is not signed but unsigned on 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

Comment: *It is signed if it fits in a signed integer* I think this statement is wrong.

Comment: A decimal integer constant is always signed. For hexadecimal constants, it can fit in a `long` but if it fit in an `unsigned int` it will be `unsigned int`. A signed integer is not a synonym of a signed `int`. The type `long` is also a signed integer type.

Comment: What happens in conversion ?? Of signed to unsigned ?