# Run-time error in a code

Tags: c, algorithm

**Problem:** On standard stream of input we get sequence of sets of numbers from diapason [0, 31]. Every set finished by **-1**. Every set may be empty and numbers may be repeated in set.
You need to find XOR of all sets and output a hexadecimal representation of result, i.e we obtain {1, 2, 3}, {3, 4}, {1, 5} and result is {2, 4, 5}, thus a hexadecimal representation is 34. Each number in the result set corresponds to bit in the 32-bit hexadecimal representation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    int32_t currentNum;
    uint32_t num = 0, result = 0;

    while (scanf("%"SCNd32, &currentNum) == 1) {
        if (currentNum != -1) {
            num |= 1 << currentNum;
        } else {
            result ^= num;
            num = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%x\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

This problem is simple and my solution is above. But I have following problem : the testing system in which I send a code return me a run-time error. I can't imagine where is mistake and I can't come up with a such test that return run-time error.
Could you give me any tips?

Comment: Have you tested it with repetitions within a set?

Comment: @Beta, yes, of course!

Comment: And? What is your simplest such test, and are you sure you expect the same result as the judge? Did the site give such an example, with the desired result?

Comment: Is it possible that the SCNd32 macro is not defined in the testing system?

Comment: did you try with "%d" instead?

Comment: So, which of the suggestions helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like `1 << 31` is undefined behavior.  See, `1` is a [signed constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11310456/1488799), and `1 << 31` is not representable in an `int`, so [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3784996/1488799).  Try `1U << currentNum` there to make it unsigned and well-defined.

Second, `SCNd32` may not be what you expect.  On my system (MinGW-w64 GCC 5.3.0 on Windows), it is not defined at all, so your program just does not compile.  Thus I can imagine it can be defined to mean something other as well, and then compile but fail at runtime.  Try a simple `"%d"` or `"%i"` there.

Third, some online judges may be configured so that calling certain functions is restricted by terminating after a call to them at runtime.  One of such functions may be `scanf` if, for example, the judge admins think you should use `fgets` for some weird reason, or `iostream` if the language is in fact C++.  This however is already guess territory.  Try reading the judge documentation to see if this is the case.

Comment: This surprises me, that the `SCNd32` macro is not defined at all in MinGW. Note that the Standard requires that this macro be defined in `inttypes.h` if the system supports 32 bit fixed-width integers.

Comment: Yes, problem was in 1 << 31.