# How much memory can we get by malloc() in x64?

Tags: c++, c, malloc

in x64, I can get not get more than 1.9G memory by malloc(), but my physical memory is 8G, why does this happen?

Comment: Is it a 32 bit or 64 bit process? Also, physical memory != virtual memory

Comment: Check your link settings--are you using a 64 bit compiler, linker, etc?

Comment: What operating system? The OS might impose per-process size limits. To tell whether you're compiling in 32-bit or 64-bit mode, check the size of a pointer: `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof (void*));`

Comment: Go to this [link][1], you'll find some information. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537967/what-is-the-limit-on-malloc-parameter-of-type-size-t-in-c-docs-say-it-has-an-up

Comment: You are most certainly compiling your program as a 32-bit process. Also, are you allocating all that in one large block or several smaller one?

Comment: In that best case as much as the relevant `size_t` can address ... - ok, a bit few as the OS also need something to live.

Answer (score 8):

This most likely happens because you're using either a 32-bit compiler, a 32-bit OS, or (possibly) both.

I simplified your code quite a bit, down to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    void *block = malloc(1024LL * 1024LL * 1024LL * 6);
    if (block)
        std::cout << "Allocated 6 Gig block\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Unable to allocate 6 Gig block.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this with a 32-bit compiler, it fails (prints out "Unable to allocated 6 Gig block." If I compile it with a 64-bit compiler, it succeeds (prints out "Allocated 6 Gig block"). I don't have a 32-bit OS handy to test it on, but I feel reasonably confident that with a 32-bit OS, it would fail as well (the 32-bit executable would act about the same it does under a 64-bit OS, and the 64-bit executable wouldn't run on a 32-bit OS at all).

```
Specs: 32-bit compilers tested: gcc 4.8.1 (MinGW), Microsoft VC++ 17.
64-bit compiler: VC++ 17.
OS: Windows 8 x64.
```

Comment: (Of course, the compiler's bitness doesn't matter; it's the compiler output's bitness. But +1 because that's pedantic...)

Comment: @Billy I'd say it's a matter of interpretation rather than pedantry. When I read "32-bit compiler", I think "a compiler that compiles 32-bit code". Compiler vendors in my experience use it the same way.

Comment: @Cody: Yeah... that's what I get for thinking in MSVC++ land, which ships with both 32 bit and 64 bit compilers targeting 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks so much, that i found my problem is that my OS is 64bit, but i think i use the 32bit compiler, because the "sizeof(void*) = 4".

Comment: @user Applications that are compiled for 32-bit run just fine on 64-bit operating systems. This is thanks to the [WOW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) emulation layer. Only the other way doesn't work (64-bit apps on 32-bit Windows). To change the bitness to x64, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx).